# Format Parameter Multiselect values

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I need to format the date of a multiselect parameter list.
I've tried to format it within the code by using:

```
to_date(eo.exam_date, 'DD-Mon-YY')
```

In both my Main Dataset and my Parameter Dataset "P_Exam_Date" however the format is still wrong see attached image:

[image]

How would I format this?

Comment: `to_char(eo.exam_date, 'DD-Mon-YY')` is the key! `to_date()` just gives a date in return with format as in `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. Whereas `to_char()` gives you a formatted(as you gave) string. So your target variable should be a String as well!

Comment: Ah wonderful, my mind is mashed today.

You should paste that in the answer so I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `to_char(eo.exam_date, 'DD-Mon-YY')`

`to_date()` just gives a date in return with format as in `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` of your SQL Session. Whereas `to_char()` gives you a formatted(as you gave) string. So your target variable should be a String as well!